# How to do facial recognition from a live webcam in Java?

Tags: image-processing, webcam, face-recognition, java

I am guessing I need 2 things:

1. A library to capture video from a webcam (that library should also show a live preview applet)
2. A library to actually do facial recognition (by facial recognition I mean not only find the region where a face is but also match or register against database of existing faces e.g. the Faces feature of iPhoto)

I am clueless where to start or which libraries to use - I found libraries that do either  1) or 2) but not sure how to interface them or if there are ones that just work out of the box and do both or should I roll something of my own??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a stand alone Java Face detection package: https://github.com/pathikrit/JFaceRecog

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is for you : a [Java binding](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) exists

> OpenCV is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both
>   academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces
>   and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android. OpenCV was
>   designed for computational efficiency and with a strong focus on
>   real-time applications. Written in optimized C/C++, the library can
>   take advantage of multi-core processing. Enabled with OpenCL, it can
>   take advantage of the hardware acceleration of the underlying
>   heterogeneous compute platform. Adopted all around the world, OpenCV
>   has more than 47 thousand people of user community and estimated
>   number of downloads exceeding 7 million. Usage ranges from interactive
>   art, to mines inspection, stitching maps on the web or through
>   advanced robotics.

Comment: Cool, I got a simple Java program running that does face detection in a live preview i.e. it shows a preview from my webcam and draws a rectangle around my face as I move around. But now, I want it to do facial recognition i.e. it either detects the person from a database of image or suggests me to save the image as an existing or new person. How do I do that? Is there something in OpenCV that already lets me do that?

Comment: I would like to know if there's a way to use OpenCV for a Java Desktop App into Windows 8?

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/9396/can-somebody-please-tell-me-how-to-install-opencv/